# How to reuse entity classes as return type when join multiple tables with spring boot and mybatis?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mybatis

For example there are 2 entity classes named A and B, when select ... from A join B, the return type shoud include fields both from A and B,i have to create a new class for it since  it is not allowed to extend multiple classes in java.Is there better way to "merge" 2 entities?

Comment: Why doesn't A just reference B if that is what you have in the database. Or just return A and B instances in a tuple: "select a, b from A a join B b on a.id = b.bId"